# Buscar los 10 porcentajes mayores dentro de un objeto Jjavascript

Tags: javascript

> AQui mi problema

```
 var data = {
      "status":"OK",
      "copyright":" Copyright (c) 2019 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
      "results":[
        {
          "congress": "113",
          "chamber": "Senate",

  "num_results": 105,
  "offset": 0,
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "A000360",
      "title": "Senator, 2nd Class",
      "short_title": "Sen.",
      "api_uri":"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/A000360.json",
      "first_name": "Lamar",
      "middle_name": null,
      "last_name": "Alexander",
      "suffix": null,
      "date_of_birth": "1940-07-03",
      "gender": "M",
      "party": "R",
      "leadership_role": null,
      "twitter_account": "SenAlexander",
      "facebook_account": "senatorlamaralexander",
      "youtube_account": "lamaralexander",
      "govtrack_id": "300002",
      "cspan_id": "5",
      "votesmart_id": "15691",
      "icpsr_id": "40304",
      "crp_id": "N00009888",
      "google_entity_id": "/m/01rbs3",
      "fec_candidate_id": "",
      "url": "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public",
      "rss_url": "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/?a=RSS.Feed",
      "contact_form": null,
      "in_office": false,
      "cook_pvi": null,
      "dw_nominate": 0.323,
      "ideal_point": 0.83068369,
      "seniority": "11",
      "next_election": "2014",
      "total_votes": 657,
      "missed_votes": 44,
      "total_present": 0,
      "last_updated": "2019-10-07 08:16:27 -0400",
      "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:tn",
      "office": null,
      "phone": null,
      "fax": null,
      "state": "TN",
      "senate_class": "2",
      "state_rank": "",
      "lis_id": "S289"
      ,"missed_votes_pct": 6.70,
      "votes_with_party_pct": 87.40,
      "votes_against_party_pct": 12.60
    },
      n..... arreglos
```

ahora, estos son los datos de 100 personas, necesito buscar los 10 mas votados y los 10 menos votados donde sus valores respectivos son: "votes_with_party_pct" "votes_against_party_pct", estoy tratando de hacerlo y no logro nada

Comment: ¿Necesitas los 10 más votados según el campo  `votes_with_party_pct` y los 10 menos votados por `votes_against_party_pct`?

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Sin ver lo que hayas intentado y una explicación del problema o dificultad encontrada, será difícil ayudarte. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Además, puedes hacer el [tour] para que comprendas un poco mejor cómo funciona el sitio. Saludos